# Select N next siblings in relation to the selected element (with unique class attached) using CSS (LESS)

Tags: html, css, less

I have HTML code below. Let's say, I'm able to attach the `selected-day` class by clicking on each span. I'm trying to select the next 6 siblings, starting from the element with the class `selected-day`.
Here's what I have came up with:

```css
#calendar span.day.selected-day {
  background-color: red;
  ~ span:nth-child(n + 6):nth-child(-n + 15) {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar">
 <span class="day">1</span>
 <span class="day">2</span>
 <span class="day">3</span>
 <span class="day">4</span>
 <span class="day">5</span>
 <span class="day selected-day">6</span>
 <span class="day">7</span>
 <span class="day">8</span>
 <span class="day">9</span>
 <span class="day">10</span>
 <span class="day">11</span>
 <span class="day">12</span>
 <span class="day">13</span>
 <span class="day">14</span>
 <span class="day">15</span>
 <span class="day">16</span>
</div>
```

While it correctly highlights selected days at the beginning:

[image]

Whenever I change the selection, it doesn't follow:

[image]

Is there any proper way to always select the next 6 sibling in relation to the element with the given class?

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you are going to toggle `.selected-day`, why not do the same for the end. Like starting point / end point. This way you paint red `.selected-day`, `.selected-day ~ span.day` and then black `.end-day ~ span.day`.

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it! Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it doesn't look elegant but you can simply add multiple selectors. Since I don't use less I write the example in native css

```
#calendar span.day.selected-day + span,
#calendar span.day.selected-day + span + span,
#calendar span.day.selected-day + span + span + span,
#calendar span.day.selected-day + span + span + span + span,
#calendar span.day.selected-day + span + span + span + span + span,
#calendar span.day.selected-day + span + span + span + span + span + span {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Edit: I tried it in LESS

```
#calendar span.day.selected-day {
  background-color: red;
  + span,
  + span + span,
  + span + span + span,
  + span + span + span + span,
  + span + span + span + span + span,
  + span + span + span + span + span + span
  {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```